# Passing Pointers to Classes in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to pass a pointer into my classes function, have it incremented, and have the variable retain it's value using pointers. Heres my code, it doesnt increment.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test 
{
public:

    int addTo();
    test(int * currentY);
private:

    int y;
};

test::test(int * currentY):
y(*currentY)
{
}

int test::addTo()
{
    y++;
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        int pointedAt = 1;
        int * number = &pointedAt;
        test t(number);
        t.addTo();
        cout <<*number;

        char f;
        cin >>f;
    }
}
```

Comment: `y` is a copy. You'll need some kind of indirection.

Comment: Surely you can reduce this to three or four lines of code.

Comment: You can make `y` a reference. `int& y;`.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test 
{
public:
    int addTo();
    test(int * currentY);

private:
    int *y;
};

test::test(int *currentY):
    y(currentY)
{}

int test::addTo()
{
    ++*y;
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        int pointedAt = 1;
        test t(&pointedAt);
        t.addTo();
        cout << pointedAt;
    }
}
```

You have to store a pointer to the integer, so it refers to the same address as the original variable.